# Extract Url & Title from link field in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I'm trying to retrieve the *URL* and the *Title* values of a [Link field](https://www.drupal.org/project/link) in **Drupal 8**.

In my custom controller, I retrieve the nodes with:

```
$storage = \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node');
$nids = $storage->getQuery()
    ->condition('type', 'partners')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->execute();

$partners = $storage->loadMultiple($nids);
```

When I loop throught all my nodes, to preprocess vars I'll give to my view, I would like to retrieve the *URL* and the *Title*.

```
foreach ($partners as $key => $partner) {
    $variables['partners'][] = array(
        'image' => $partner->field_logo->entity->url(),
        'url'   => $partner->field_link->value, // Can't retrieve values of link field
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't found how to retrieve the *URL* and the *Title* of **field_link**.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

At the node level, inside your Twig template you can use:

`{{ content.field_link.0['#url'] }}` & `{{ content.field_link.0['#title'] }}`

**For example:**

`<a href="{{ content.field_link.0['#url'] }}">{{ content.field_link.0['#title'] }}</a>`

`field_link` being the name of the link field in question.

Comment: I have overridden `views-view-fields.html.twig` where I want to extract the `URL` part from `title` and assign it to a separate link. I tried two wild gueses: `{{ fields.title.content.0['#url'] }}` and `{{ fields.title.content['#url'] }}`. However none of those worked :) How I can do this?

Comment: I think you need to `|render ` the field, this seems to work for me: `{{ fields.title.content.0['#url']|render }}` to get the actual URL

Comment: what if we are not in the node level instead we created the view and used a block?

Comment: Also tried the above render technique ... didn't work :(

Comment: @SubrataSarkar I think you can do this by adding a field path:content.

Comment: @omer you can use {{content.field_link.0['#url']}} at block level (in block--bundle--block-name.html.twig). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 15):

I just found the solution ...

```
$partner->field_lien->uri // The url
$partner->field_lien->title // The title
```

My bad, hope it could help someone.

Comment: How can I get URI using Twig syntax?

Comment: @FredK For Twig: `$partner.field_lien.uri`

Comment: +1, but how the hell do you reach this information? 
Is there a documentation anywhere I can find a listing of each attribut for each type of field. example : link > uri/title/... , text > value ?

Answer (score 12):

Just to piggyback on the above, if you have an external link,

```
$node->field_name->uri
```

Will give you the URL, but if it's an internal you may need to tweak a bit more:

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;

$mylink = Url::fromUri($node->field_name[0]->uri);
$mylink->toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution.

In fact, you can retrieve the direct url with **$node->field_name->entity->url();**

Hope I help you.

Comment: @KevinWenger, are you sure? I get a nullpointer exception if I try your code on a field collection link field.

Comment: It depends the type of `field_name`. In my example, if your `field_name` is an *entityreference* (link to node, taxonomy or any other entity) then it would works. Otherwise, indeed for a standard link field you should do `$node->field_name->first()->uri`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do this in a field template instead of a node template do this:

```
{% for item in items %}
  {{ item.content['#url'] }}
  {{ item.content['#title'] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Alternately, if this is not a multi-value field you can just do this instead:

```
{{ items|first.content['#url'] }}
{{ items|first.content['#title'] }}
```

Comment: This isn't working for me.  {{item.content}} shows the linked file.  However {{ item.content['#url'] }} isn't giving the url in field--field_down.html.twig for me.

Comment: You saved me 2 hours. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Updated for Drupal 8

To get the url all you need to do is:

```
{{ content.field_link_name[0]['#url'] }}
```

To get the link text:

```
{{ content.field_link_name[0]['#title'] }}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can render either the uri or text of a link field directly in the twig template. In the case of a node you can use either of the following within the twig template file (assumes the machine name of your link field is `field_link`):

```
{{ node.field_link.uri }}

{{ node.field_link.title }}
```

Comment: Weird, other solutions like `{{ entity.field_link[0]['#url'] }}` was working on certain `node—view--xxx` but not all views. Your solution works perfectly well in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me in twig:

```
content.field_link_name.0['#title']        // title
content.field_link_name.0['#url_title']    // url value
```

*you should use: "Separate link text and URL" widget in display

Comment: This one worked me using a paragraphs with a link field and i configured the widget to display in the way mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it in a preprocess, I'd suggest to base your code on LinkSeparateFormatter.php. It shows the idea on how to get the title from the link field. Here's a way to do it.

```
use Drupal\Component\Utility\Unicode;

//...

$field_link = $entity->field_link->first();
$link_url = $field_link->getUrl();
$link_data = $field_link->toArray();
// If you want to truncate the url
$link_title = Unicode::truncate($link_url->toString(), 40, FALSE, TRUE);
if(!empty($link_data['title'])){
  // You could truncate here as well
  $link_title = $link_data['title'];
}
$variables['content'] = [
  '#type' => 'link',
  '#url' => $link_url,
  '#title' => $link_title,
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this link separation for ECK fields and this solution really helped me. I have updated the code for ECK fields for apply inline style in twig file like this:

`<a style="color: {{ entity.field_link_color[0] }};" href="{{ entity.field_link[0]['#url'] }}"> {{ entity.field_link[0]['#title'] }}   </a>`

To get url:
`{{ entity.field_link[0]['#url'] }}`

To get link title: 
`{{ entity.field_link[0]['#title'] }}`

Answer (score 0):

After rendering a block if you want to access the link field used in it then you can use like this  $render['field_target_url']['#items']->uri  inside node preprocess hook.

Answer (score 0):

One more way is to add another field Path:Content if you are trying to fetch the URL in Views Fields