# Drupal links showing internal: and entity:

Tags: drupal-8

Drupal links start showing `internal:/` and `entity:` at the beginning of the link URI value. Those are useless. I need to remove `internal:/` and `entity:` in order to make links reachable.

How to fix that that?

I get the URI value with:

```
paragraph.field_stage_element_hp_link.uri.value
```

Answer (score -1):

**Edit: Use this method as a last resort. There are a lot of [better](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199262/how-to-get-the-valid-url-of-a-link-field-from-within-a-twig-template) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499554/extract-url-title-from-link-field-in-drupal-8) to do this.**

To get rid of those two annoying prefixes, you first must know where they come from. There are 3 types of link :

- An internal link as `/my-awesome-alias` adds the prefix `internal:` to your URI,
- A node link inserted with autocomplete is converted to a node URI and is like `entity:/node/3` and thus adds the prefix `entity:` to your URI,
- An external link as `https://www.openstreetmap.org` lets your URI as it is.

Treat those 3 cases with 3 conditions:

```php
{% set uri = paragraph.field_stage_element_hp_link.uri.value %}

{% if uri matches '{^https?://}' %}
  {% set url = uri %}
{% elseif uri matches '{^internal:}' %}
  {% set url = uri|split(':')[1] %}
{% elseif uri matches '{^entity:}' %}
  {% set url = path('entity.node.canonical', {'node':  uri | split('/')[1]}) %}
{% endif %}

<a href="{{ url }}"> My awesome link </a>
```